# change behavior of function in TestCase

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

I have sendmail function that is being called in post_save signal. I would like this function just to return None instead for all test cases. How to achieve this? Use patch from mock.patch in setUp? How?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the question because it will resolve your problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you may want to mock whatever functions you are using in your `post_save` signal.

And an even better idea would be to mock the functionality inside the signal.

```py
def do_something():
    ...

@receiver(...)
def signal_handler_post_save(sender, *args, **kwargs):
   do_something()
```

Then in your tests:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

...
    @patch('path_to_your_signal_module.do_something')
    def test_my_test_case(self, do_something):
        self.assertEqual(do_something.call_count, 1)
...
```